# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException C#, winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

My application randomly crash, I don't know where is problemy, only what I have is log. Application is on the network drive, when application run on local machine everything is alright. I'm trying check under WinDbg but when I do this application won't crash, same situation is when I trying debug code on network drive. No throw exception. Network disk is localize on WIndows 2012, I tryed change to some another computer and share disk but with same effect. Also all dll is merge to one exe (I was thinking this is a problem with loss connection and accessing to dll)

Application: Controlling.exe
    Architecture version: v4.0.30319
    Description: the process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
    Information about the exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
       w Rena.GridForm.toolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(System.EventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(System.EventArgs, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(System.EventArgs, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemEventType)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons, Int32)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
       w System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
       w System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
       w Rena.StartForm.Main(System.String[])

The name of the application causing the error: Controlling.exe, version: 1.0.7012.19207, time stamp: 0x5c8a217f
    The name of the module causing the error: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3362.0, timestamp: 0x5c2fd0c9
    Exception code: 0xc0000006
    Error offset: 0x000a341b
    The identifier of the process causing the error: 0x5294
    The time the application started causing the error: 0x01d4da5e8ec251db
    The application path causing the error: W:\ APPLICATIONS \ CONTROLLING \ Controlling.exe
    The path of the module causing the error: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ clr.dll
    Report ID: 068f4b8c-6b45-4010-a633-991edc807e01
    The full package name causing the error:
    The application identifier relative to the error package:

Comment: See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b85fc9dd-acc5-42dc-a28e-b70953bf1170/unhandled-exception-systemruntimeinteropservicessehexception-additional-information-external?forum=vcgeneral). It might help you.

Comment: If the previous link is unhelpful, feel free to post your code you perform in the Rena.GridForm.toolStripMenuItem_Click event handler, so that everybody can investigate it.

Comment: Does your application work from the network drive if you don't merge all of the DLLs into the executable? Some DevExpress dlls are loaded at runtime and cannot be merged together.